# Can someone explain what WhiteBox.setInternalState(uniUnderTest,"test",test) does-mokito

Tags: java, junit

Can someone explain what 
WhiteBox.setInternalState(uniUnderTest,"test",test) does-mokito?

Comment: Why don't you try it and tell us what it did for you?